# Country of Manufacturer system attribute how do I export the ISO code in a dataflow export?

Tags: admin, attributes

With the system attribute country_of_manufacture i'm told that the actual data that is there is the 2 char ISO code but when I come to export a product the actual data that comes out is the full country name.

What I'm wanting to do is when I export it outputs the 2 char ISO country code

The reason for this is that I'm going to be using linnworks for multi channel selling and Amazon use the ISO code so it would be easier for me when i import into linnworks that I can set that as one of the attributes.

I've tried setting a new attribute (called country_of_manufacture_iso) and have set the Admin field as (for example) CL and the English to Chile which does work BUT it means that CL is what is shown in admin (whereas I would want it to say Chile)

Comment: Do you mean to create a new attribute? Currently, country of manufacturer stores the 2-character country ISO code in the database and shows the actual country name in dropdowns.

Comment: really? When I export via dataflow profile though it exports it as the country name not the 2-character country ISO. What I need it to do is show actual name in dropdowns (of admin) and when I do a dataflow profile export it exports the 2 char iso code

Comment: I'm not too familiar with dataflow. You may want to revise your question (and the title and tags) to indicate that it's a dataflow issue; someone with more experience in that area may jump in.